# Can't point or store the elements of array in a new array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have an `arrFillRandom` function which fill an array with random numbers and prints it out. Here it is:

```
void arrFillRandom(int *arrayPtr, int sizeRow, int sizeColumn, int randomRange) {
    int i, j;

    arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizeRow * sizeColumn);

    for (i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++)
            (arrayPtr + i)[j] = (rand() % randomRange);
    
    for (i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++)
            printf("%d\t", (arrayPtr + i)[j]);
    }
}
```

And here is my `main`:

```
int main() {
void arrFillRandom(int *arrayPtr, int sizeRow, int sizeColumn, int randomRange);

int matrix1[2][3];
int matrix2[3][2];

int *ptr1, *ptr2;
ptr1 = &matrix1[0][0];
ptr2 = &matrix2[0][0];

arrFillRandom(ptr1, 2, 3, 10);
arrFillRandom(ptr2, 3, 2, 10);

printf("\n%d", ptr1[0]);

return 0;
}
```

My problem is that `ptr1` or `ptr2` doesn't point to array which `arrFillRandom` filled before.
In `arrFillRandom` function, I print out the matrix with random numbers. For example:

> **1, 0, 9** // first row of first matrix
>
> **0, 9, 4** // second row of first matrix
>
> **8, 2** // first row of second matrix
>
> **2, 5** // second row of second matrix
>
> **5, 5** // third row of second matrix

But in `main`, when I want to print first element of this matrix:

```
printf("\n%d", ptr1[0]);
```

This line should print **1**, but it prints irrelevant number such as 4096.

So why I couldn't store that matrix in this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `void arrFillRandom()` function allocates *new* memory and fills that with
random numbers. `arrayPtr` is a *local variable* inside the function, and assigning a new value to it
does not change the passed arguments `ptr1` or `ptr2`.

To fill the arrays whose addresses are passed to the function, simply remove the line

```
arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizeRow * sizeColumn);
```

You also have to change

```
(arrayPtr + i)[j]
```

to

```
arrayPtr[sizeColumn * i + j]
```

inside that function.

Comment: Thanks for solution but I'm confused a little bit. If I don't write anything about memory, if I don't use `malloc`, how do compiler know that how many spaces should be allocated for this array? I guess, `matrix1[2][3]` and `matrix2[2][2]` is enough about that, right?
When I use pointers with arrays, sometimes can't understand things easily.

Comment: @lombranzo: Yes, `matrix1[2][3]` *is* already an array. Btw., you can call your function as `arrFillRandom(matrix1, 2, 3, 10);` because an array "decays" to a pointer to the first element when passed as an argument to a function.

Comment: I know but in assignment, it is asked to call that function like I wrote. Thanks again. :)

Comment: omg, I have exactly the same problem about matrix multiplication. I would be appreaciate if you could take a look at: [link](https://ideone.com/NEq4Zl)

Comment: @lombranzo: There was still another error in your arrFillRandom function, so that the matrices where not filled correctly. See updated answer.

Comment: How can I do that by using pointer offset notation? `*((*(arrayPtr+i))+j)` is this correct to do that? But when I use this, when I use asteriks(*), then some errors appear again. How should I do this? 
I'm really so appreciate for your patience Martin. If you suggest me some web page or video about pointers, that would be great.